# Perception and Time

Tags: history-of-philosophy, time, perception, art

How is the subject of 'Time' portrayed? Is the record of human awareness and understanding of 'Time' better articulated by the history of Philosophy or better expressed by the history of Art?

In advance of your thoughtful consideration, thank you to any and all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it may be of interest. "Modernism, Time and Consciousness: the influence of Henri Bergson and Marcel Proust". https://www.bl.uk/20th-century-literature/articles/modernism-time-and-consciousness-the-influence-of-henri-bergson-and-marcel-proust

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the SEP article on [Time](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/).  It doesn't quite have the art history side of things, but it does a decent job of capturing the awareness of time from a philosophical perspective.

Comment: This seems almost too broad of a question to answer here.  If you could narrow the question down and provide a reference for context it might help someone provide an answer.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that our understanding of time has evolved at all over time. For the mystic time is what it always was and for the scholastic thinker it is as much of a mystery as ever. Such a history might be rather short as a philosophical account, but time as viewed by artists may make for an interesting historical survey. .  .